# Javascript - switch is for strings only?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Im not sure if I can use switch only for strings or that I can use it for numbers, booleans or events.

Comment: just for anything which is comparable.

Answer (score 3):

`switch()` can be used to compare any types: strings, objects, numbers.
The important thing to notice that `switch()` uses [strict type comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness): `===`.

For example:

**Comparing strings**

```
var a = '1';

switch (a) {
  case 1:
    console.log(1); // '1' === 1 returns false, no match
    break;
  default:
    console.log('No match'); // will print 'No match'
}
```

**Comparing objects**

```
var a = 1;

switch (a.constructor) {
   case Number:
     console.log('number'); // prints 'number'
     break;
   case String:
     console.log('string');
     break;
   default:
     console.log('no match');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Im not sure if I can use switch only for strings

Nope, it should just be a **valid** **expression** as per the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-switch-statement)

See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/Lkngm5j8/),

this code alerts `right`

```
var a =1;
var b = 2;

switch(a+b)
{
  case 1:
     alert("wrong");
  break;
  case 2:
     alert("wrong");
  break;
  case 3:
     alert("right");
  break;
  default:
     alert("wrong");
  break;
}
```